# "for loop" for ValueCollection

Tags: c#

Is there a way to iterate ValueCollection using straight for loop? (not foreach)

e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, List<long>>.ValueCollection somevalues = somecollection.Value.Values;

for(int i = 0; i< somevalues.Count; i++)
{
 //now what?
}
```

Comment: Why exactly don't you want to use `foreach` ? if you need to know the index of the current item, you can just maintain a counter variable, or use the overload of Select mentioned by Jon...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No - there's no indexer or anything similar for `ValueCollection`. I suppose you could use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < someValues.Count; i++)
{
    var item = someValues.ElementAt(i);
    ...
}
```

but that would perform like a dog :) (Just iteration would be O(n^2), as it would be like [Schlemiel the Painter](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html).)

Why do you want to do this? If you want items with elements, just keep a counter or use the [overload of `Select` that passes in the index as well as the item](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx).

Comment: Lol, nice one Jon. +1 :-) ToArray() would be more perfomant than ElementAt(), but it'd still be a waste of time compared to the foreach.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *have* to use an index in a for loop...

```
for (var en = somevalues.GetEnumerator(); en.MoveNext(); )
{
    var item = en.Current;
    // do something useful...
}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a less readable version of `foreach`? (And it doesn't dispose the enumerator either.)

Comment: Yes, basically it's just the same as a `foreach` (and yes, I forgot to dispose the enumerator, shame on me). But it does answer the question : i'm not using the `foreach` instruction ;). Anyway, I don't see any reason not to use `foreach` in that case...

Answer (score 1):

not out of the box. some collections do not have index operators ( `myCollection[ someIndex ]` )

Answer (score 1):

Your most likely reason for wanting this is to be able to use that index in some other way.  Simply stick with a foreach loop, initialize a variable to zero before the loop and increment it at the bottom of the loop.